# The circle is not an ANR

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, fixed-point-theorems

It is claimed in the [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolute_neighbourhood_extensor) that $S^1$ is an ANR. However this seems to be wrong as [there is no retraction from the disc onto the circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84324/17929). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*I'll assume you're talking about the metric space variety of ARs and ANRs*]

You seem to be confused between the definition of a space being an AR (absolute retract) and an ANR (absolute neighbourhood retract). In fact, a metric space is an AR if and only if it is contractible and an ANR.

An ANR is a metric space $X$ such that for any other metric space $Y$ for which $X$ is a closed subset of $Y$, there exists an open subset $X \subset U\subset Y$ such that $X$ is a retract of $U$.

In the case of a circle $X=S^1$ and $Y=D^2$ the disk, we can take $U = D^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and then $S^1$ is a retract of $U$ under the usual radial projection map.

It's well known that every topological manifold is an ANR.