# Proving that $S^1$ is not a retract of the disk $D^2$ or of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ using a problem that I already solved.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory, retraction

> I've proven that "If $A$ is a retract of $X$ and $X$ is contractible, then $A$ is also contractible."
>
> Can I use this to prove the circle $S^1$ isn't a retract of the disk $D^2$ or of the plane $\Bbb R^2$?If so, how can I do that?

**My trial:**

$(1)$ I was allowed to take this theorem:

> The circle $S^1$ isn' t contractible,

for granted and I can use it. So I decided to prove that the disk $D^2$ (and the plane $\Bbb R^2$ )is contractible (which can be done because any convex space is homotopically equivalent to the space of the one point (by the straight line homotopy and because $D^2$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$ are convex spaces)) and to assume that $S^1$ is a retract of the disk $D^2$ ( or of the plane $\Bbb R^2)$ and then, by the problem I've proven, I should conclude $S^1$ is contractible, which contradicts the theorem  above that I took for granted .... am I correct in this proof?

---

$(2)$ I have found a solution in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84312/is-the-unit-circle-s1-a-retract-of-mathbbr2) which uses the idea of *the fundamental group and Brouwer fixed point theorem*, but, unfortunately, these tools I haven't studied yet.

Comment: I think your proof by contradiction idea works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By contradiction is fine, in detail:

1. Assume $S^1$ is a retract of $D^2$.
2. $D^2$ is contractible (by straight line segments to the origin, as you say).
3. Quoted theorem applied to $1$ and $2$: $S^1$ is contractible.
4. **Fact given to you**: $S^1$ is not contractible.

Hence contradiction from $3$ and $4$ and so $1$ must be false: $S^1$ is *not* a retract of $D^2$.

Another proof could use the Brouwer fixed point theorem:

1. Assume $S^1$ is a retract of $D^2$.
2. Theorem by Brouwer: every $f: D^2 \to D^2$ that is continuous has a fixed point. (i.e. $D^2$ has the FPP (fixed point property)).
3. Theorem: if $X$ has the FPP and $A$ is a retract of $X$, then $A$ has the FPP too. (If $g: A \to A$ is continuous, and $r$ is a retraction, apply the FPP to $g \circ r: X \to A \subseteq X$, etc.)
4. $1$ to $3$ together imply $S^1$ has the FPP.
5. Fact: $S^1$ does not have the FPP (consider the rotation around $90$ degrees either way, e.g.).
6. Contradiction between $4$ and $5$ shows $1$ must be false again.